# how to get high and low point from a sine wave data array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is an example array. I am trying to get values of two cycles, for example this array would return keys 21 and 143 as lowest values, 80 and 204 as highest values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:00
            [v] => 1.443
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:06
            [v] => 1.319
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:12
            [v] => 1.199
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:18
            [v] => 1.082
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:24
            [v] => 0.969
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:30
            [v] => 0.861
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:36
            [v] => 0.757
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:42
            [v] => 0.658
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:48
            [v] => 0.565
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 00:54
            [v] => 0.477
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:00
            [v] => 0.395
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:06
            [v] => 0.320
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:12
            [v] => 0.251
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:18
            [v] => 0.190
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:24
            [v] => 0.135
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:30
            [v] => 0.088
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:36
            [v] => 0.049
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:42
            [v] => 0.017
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:48
            [v] => -0.007
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 01:54
            [v] => -0.023
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:00
            [v] => -0.031
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:06
            [v] => -0.031
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:12
            [v] => -0.024
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:18
            [v] => -0.008
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:24
            [v] => 0.015
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:30
            [v] => 0.046
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:36
            [v] => 0.084
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:42
            [v] => 0.129
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:48
            [v] => 0.181
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 02:54
            [v] => 0.240
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:00
            [v] => 0.305
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:06
            [v] => 0.377
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:12
            [v] => 0.454
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:18
            [v] => 0.537
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:24
            [v] => 0.625
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:30
            [v] => 0.718
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:36
            [v] => 0.816
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:42
            [v] => 0.919
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:48
            [v] => 1.025
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 03:54
            [v] => 1.136
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:00
            [v] => 1.251
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:06
            [v] => 1.370
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:12
            [v] => 1.492
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:18
            [v] => 1.617
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:24
            [v] => 1.746
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:30
            [v] => 1.877
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:36
            [v] => 2.010
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:42
            [v] => 2.146
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:48
            [v] => 2.284
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 04:54
            [v] => 2.424
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:00
            [v] => 2.566
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:06
            [v] => 2.708
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:12
            [v] => 2.851
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:18
            [v] => 2.995
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:24
            [v] => 3.139
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:30
            [v] => 3.282
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:36
            [v] => 3.425
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:42
            [v] => 3.566
        )

    [58] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:48
            [v] => 3.705
        )

    [59] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 05:54
            [v] => 3.842
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:00
            [v] => 3.977
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:06
            [v] => 4.108
        )

    [62] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:12
            [v] => 4.236
        )

    [63] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:18
            [v] => 4.359
        )

    [64] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:24
            [v] => 4.478
        )

    [65] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:30
            [v] => 4.592
        )

    [66] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:36
            [v] => 4.700
        )

    [67] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:42
            [v] => 4.802
        )

    [68] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:48
            [v] => 4.898
        )

    [69] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 06:54
            [v] => 4.988
        )

    [70] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:00
            [v] => 5.070
        )

    [71] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:06
            [v] => 5.145
        )

    [72] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:12
            [v] => 5.213
        )

    [73] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:18
            [v] => 5.273
        )

    [74] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:24
            [v] => 5.325
        )

    [75] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:30
            [v] => 5.370
        )

    [76] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:36
            [v] => 5.406
        )

    [77] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:42
            [v] => 5.434
        )

    [78] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:48
            [v] => 5.454
        )

    [79] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 07:54
            [v] => 5.467
        )

    [80] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:00
            [v] => 5.471
        )

    [81] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:06
            [v] => 5.467
        )

    [82] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:12
            [v] => 5.455
        )

    [83] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:18
            [v] => 5.436
        )

    [84] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:24
            [v] => 5.409
        )

    [85] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:30
            [v] => 5.375
        )

    [86] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:36
            [v] => 5.334
        )

    [87] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:42
            [v] => 5.285
        )

    [88] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:48
            [v] => 5.230
        )

    [89] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 08:54
            [v] => 5.169
        )

    [90] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:00
            [v] => 5.101
        )

    [91] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:06
            [v] => 5.027
        )

    [92] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:12
            [v] => 4.947
        )

    [93] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:18
            [v] => 4.862
        )

    [94] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:24
            [v] => 4.771
        )

    [95] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:30
            [v] => 4.675
        )

    [96] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:36
            [v] => 4.575
        )

    [97] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:42
            [v] => 4.471
        )

    [98] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:48
            [v] => 4.362
        )

    [99] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 09:54
            [v] => 4.250
        )

    [100] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:00
            [v] => 4.134
        )

    [101] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:06
            [v] => 4.015
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:12
            [v] => 3.893
        )

    [103] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:18
            [v] => 3.768
        )

    [104] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:24
            [v] => 3.642
        )

    [105] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:30
            [v] => 3.513
        )

    [106] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:36
            [v] => 3.383
        )

    [107] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:42
            [v] => 3.251
        )

    [108] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:48
            [v] => 3.119
        )

    [109] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 10:54
            [v] => 2.986
        )

    [110] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:00
            [v] => 2.852
        )

    [111] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:06
            [v] => 2.718
        )

    [112] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:12
            [v] => 2.584
        )

    [113] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:18
            [v] => 2.450
        )

    [114] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:24
            [v] => 2.317
        )

    [115] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:30
            [v] => 2.185
        )

    [116] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:36
            [v] => 2.054
        )

    [117] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:42
            [v] => 1.924
        )

    [118] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:48
            [v] => 1.796
        )

    [119] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 11:54
            [v] => 1.669
        )

    [120] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:00
            [v] => 1.545
        )

    [121] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:06
            [v] => 1.423
        )

    [122] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:12
            [v] => 1.303
        )

    [123] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:18
            [v] => 1.186
        )

    [124] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:24
            [v] => 1.073
        )

    [125] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:30
            [v] => 0.963
        )

    [126] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:36
            [v] => 0.856
        )

    [127] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:42
            [v] => 0.754
        )

    [128] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:48
            [v] => 0.656
        )

    [129] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 12:54
            [v] => 0.563
        )

    [130] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:00
            [v] => 0.474
        )

    [131] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:06
            [v] => 0.391
        )

    [132] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:12
            [v] => 0.314
        )

    [133] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:18
            [v] => 0.242
        )

    [134] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:24
            [v] => 0.177
        )

    [135] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:30
            [v] => 0.118
        )

    [136] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:36
            [v] => 0.066
        )

    [137] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:42
            [v] => 0.021
        )

    [138] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:48
            [v] => -0.016
        )

    [139] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 13:54
            [v] => -0.047
        )

    [140] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:00
            [v] => -0.069
        )

    [141] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:06
            [v] => -0.084
        )

    [142] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:12
            [v] => -0.091
        )

    [143] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:18
            [v] => -0.091
        )

    [144] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:24
            [v] => -0.082
        )

    [145] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:30
            [v] => -0.066
        )

    [146] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:36
            [v] => -0.041
        )

    [147] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:42
            [v] => -0.009
        )

    [148] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:48
            [v] => 0.030
        )

    [149] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 14:54
            [v] => 0.077
        )

    [150] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:00
            [v] => 0.131
        )

    [151] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:06
            [v] => 0.192
        )

    [152] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:12
            [v] => 0.260
        )

    [153] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:18
            [v] => 0.334
        )

    [154] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:24
            [v] => 0.415
        )

    [155] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:30
            [v] => 0.502
        )

    [156] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:36
            [v] => 0.594
        )

    [157] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:42
            [v] => 0.692
        )

    [158] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:48
            [v] => 0.796
        )

    [159] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 15:54
            [v] => 0.904
        )

    [160] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:00
            [v] => 1.016
        )

    [161] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:06
            [v] => 1.134
        )

    [162] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:12
            [v] => 1.255
        )

    [163] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:18
            [v] => 1.381
        )

    [164] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:24
            [v] => 1.510
        )

    [165] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:30
            [v] => 1.642
        )

    [166] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:36
            [v] => 1.778
        )

    [167] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:42
            [v] => 1.917
        )

    [168] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:48
            [v] => 2.059
        )

    [169] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 16:54
            [v] => 2.203
        )

    [170] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:00
            [v] => 2.349
        )

    [171] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:06
            [v] => 2.498
        )

    [172] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:12
            [v] => 2.648
        )

    [173] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:18
            [v] => 2.799
        )

    [174] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:24
            [v] => 2.952
        )

    [175] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:30
            [v] => 3.105
        )

    [176] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:36
            [v] => 3.258
        )

    [177] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:42
            [v] => 3.412
        )

    [178] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:48
            [v] => 3.564
        )

    [179] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 17:54
            [v] => 3.716
        )

    [180] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:00
            [v] => 3.867
        )

    [181] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:06
            [v] => 4.016
        )

    [182] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:12
            [v] => 4.162
        )

    [183] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:18
            [v] => 4.306
        )

    [184] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:24
            [v] => 4.446
        )

    [185] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:30
            [v] => 4.582
        )

    [186] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:36
            [v] => 4.715
        )

    [187] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:42
            [v] => 4.842
        )

    [188] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:48
            [v] => 4.964
        )

    [189] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 18:54
            [v] => 5.081
        )

    [190] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:00
            [v] => 5.192
        )

    [191] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:06
            [v] => 5.296
        )

    [192] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:12
            [v] => 5.393
        )

    [193] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:18
            [v] => 5.484
        )

    [194] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:24
            [v] => 5.567
        )

    [195] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:30
            [v] => 5.642
        )

    [196] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:36
            [v] => 5.710
        )

    [197] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:42
            [v] => 5.770
        )

    [198] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:48
            [v] => 5.821
        )

    [199] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 19:54
            [v] => 5.865
        )

    [200] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:00
            [v] => 5.900
        )

    [201] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:06
            [v] => 5.927
        )

    [202] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:12
            [v] => 5.946
        )

    [203] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:18
            [v] => 5.956
        )

    [204] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:24
            [v] => 5.959
        )

    [205] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:30
            [v] => 5.954
        )

    [206] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:36
            [v] => 5.940
        )

    [207] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:42
            [v] => 5.919
        )

    [208] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:48
            [v] => 5.890
        )

    [209] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 20:54
            [v] => 5.854
        )

    [210] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:00
            [v] => 5.810
        )

    [211] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:06
            [v] => 5.760
        )

    [212] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:12
            [v] => 5.702
        )

    [213] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:18
            [v] => 5.638
        )

    [214] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:24
            [v] => 5.567
        )

    [215] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:30
            [v] => 5.490
        )

    [216] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:36
            [v] => 5.407
        )

    [217] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:42
            [v] => 5.318
        )

    [218] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:48
            [v] => 5.224
        )

    [219] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 21:54
            [v] => 5.125
        )

    [220] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:00
            [v] => 5.021
        )

    [221] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:06
            [v] => 4.912
        )

    [222] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:12
            [v] => 4.798
        )

    [223] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:18
            [v] => 4.681
        )

    [224] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:24
            [v] => 4.560
        )

    [225] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:30
            [v] => 4.435
        )

    [226] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:36
            [v] => 4.307
        )

    [227] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:42
            [v] => 4.176
        )

    [228] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:48
            [v] => 4.043
        )

    [229] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 22:54
            [v] => 3.908
        )

    [230] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:00
            [v] => 3.771
        )

    [231] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:06
            [v] => 3.632
        )

    [232] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:12
            [v] => 3.492
        )

    [233] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:18
            [v] => 3.351
        )

    [234] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:24
            [v] => 3.209
        )

    [235] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:30
            [v] => 3.067
        )

    [236] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:36
            [v] => 2.925
        )

    [237] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:42
            [v] => 2.783
        )

    [238] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:48
            [v] => 2.642
        )

    [239] => Array
        (
            [t] => 2016-08-31 23:54
            [v] => 2.502
        )

)
```

This is my code. Sometimes it returns the right results but sometimes not. what am i doing wrong?

```
$high_low = $high_final = $low_final = array();
    $high = $low = $result_obj[0]['v'];
    $high_flag=true; $low_flag=true; 

    for($i=0; $i<count($result_obj); $i++){
        $todays_h_l = $result_obj[$i];
        $high_low[$todays_h_l['t']] = $todays_h_l['v'];

        if( $low_flag && $todays_h_l['v'] < $low ){                
            $low = $todays_h_l['v'];

            if(!isset($result_obj[$i+1]) || (isset($result_obj[$i+1]) && $result_obj[$i+1]['v'] > $low)){
                $low_final[$todays_h_l['t']] = $todays_h_l['v'];
                $low = 1;
                $low_flag=false; $high_flag=true; 
            }
        }

        if( $high_flag && $todays_h_l['v'] > $high ){
            $high = $todays_h_l['v'];

            if(!isset($result_obj[$i+1]) || (isset($result_obj[$i+1]) && $result_obj[$i+1]['v'] < $high)){                
                $high_final[$todays_h_l['t']] = $todays_h_l['v'];
                $high = 4;
                $high_flag=false; $low_flag=true; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lookup `min()` & `max()` functions from php

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions min/max just will give him _the_ maximum, not which entries are at the maximum.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions It would not solve my issue. min and max would return just two values.

Comment: @Animesh Nandi That hint was for maybe writing cleaner code. ANd you can use the functions in many ways.

Comment: @bwoebi Same here, i just want to point out helpfull functions, just comment not an answer

Comment: @bwoebi Me too! Why he wants 2 low values and to high values entries as expected?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Oh, he seems to want _all_ the **local** minima.

Comment: @bwoebi Ok, i thing i get it, he wants evry high and low peak of the given data, if the sinus has 3 peaks low/high, thus should be collected i thing!

Comment: @bwoebi Yes! As i said, it is a sine wave if you plot the data into a graph. I need the highest and lowest point for every cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works better for your problem.

```
//example data
$result_obj = array(
['v'=>1],['v'=>2],['v'=>3.1],['v'=>2],['v'=>1],['v'=>0.1],['v'=>1],
['v'=>2],['v'=>3.2],['v'=>2],['v'=>1],['v'=>0.2],['v'=>1],['v'=>2],
['v'=>3.3],['v'=>2],['v'=>1],['v'=>0.3],['v'=>1]);
//test up or down - here it means the value grows up
$lookupWay = (bool)(($result_obj[0]['v']<$result_obj[1]['v']));
$collectMAX=array();
$collectMIN=array();
foreach($result_obj as $idx=>$set){
    //we lookup for max, because data is grow up
    if($lookupWay && isset($result_obj[$idx+1])){
        //data goes back down, so     current is max
        if($set['v']>$result_obj[$idx+1]['v']){
            $collectMAX[]=$set['v'];
            $lookupWay=false;
        }

    //we lookup for min
    } else if(isset($result_obj[$idx+1])) {
        //data goes back up,current is min
        if($set['v']<$result_obj[$idx+1]['v']){
            $collectMIN[]=$set['v'];
            $lookupWay=true;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($collectMAX);//holds all high peaks
var_dump($collectMIN);//holds all low peaks
```

But thing you have to fine tune it a little. For cases if the first values are equal and so on...

Comment: Working on a partial solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979227/get-extremes-from-list-of-numbers

Comment: I resolved the issue. Thanks for the help. I tested your code and it works, well after some modifications. It does not give me exact result but it enough to get it done. Thanks again.