# PHP - Find turning points in array data (high and low) based on range

Tags: php, arrays, analysis

```
$data = array(5,0,15,20,22,14,13,15,12,22,40,25);
```

[image]

Hi , i want to traverse the data points above and find the turning points based on a range.

The way i'm tackling it so far is simply taking the $array[$i] - $array[$i-1] , and if the absolute difference is greater than the range - i'm taking it as a turning point . however - the logic is flawed as if it moved slightly up and then back down - it breaks the cycle.

[image]

The 3 down values should have been enough to make X , a turning point downwards , but because they individually do not meet the range - they are discarded .

Any solutions ?

```
if($diff >= 0)
{
  $diff_up = $diff_up + $diff;
}
else
{
  $diff_down = $diff_down + abs($diff);
}


if((($diff_up-$diff_down) >=$range) && ($pivot_type != "UP"))
{
  echo "Pivot UP at : ".$current;
  break;
}
else if((($diff_down-$diff_up) >$range) && ($pivot_type != "DOWN"))
{
  echo "Pivot DOWN at : ".$current;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Could you more clearly state the criteria for a "turning point"? You'll most likely need a slightly complicated algorithm for this.

Comment: In the array, where is the turning points? Show us a expected output array

Comment: @Kylon Tyner - basically the points where the graphs starts moving up or down , given a range e.g : 20

Comment: @Andreas - [5,0,22,13,40]

Comment: Should it not be [5,0,22,12,40]?

Comment: You should not keep separate tracks of the up and down diffs. The general direction of the graph is one way at a time. It goes either up or down. Keep a single sum of diffs that tells you how much is the current point above or below the most recent turning point.

Comment: I think a better approach is to run it two steps. On the first step decide what points do not make much difference in the graph trend and simply remove them from the data set. `20` (`#3`) could go as it is really close to `22` (`#4`) and it doesn't break the trend. `14`, `13`, `15` could also go as they only make the graph to wobble, etc. In the second step find the turning points. Between two turning points the graph should follow a single trend: go either up or down. The minor variations should have been removed on step 1.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is all local minima and maxima, [This is a good article](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/05/21/computer-algorithms-minimum-and-maximum/]).

I made this (with inspiration from:
 [get extremes from list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979227/get-extremes-from-list-of-numbers)):

```
<?php
$data = array(5,0,15,20,22,14,13,15,12,22,40,25);

function minima_and_maxima(array $array){
  $maxima = [];
  $minima = [];

  $maxima[] = $array[0];
  for($i = 1; $i < count($array) - 1; $i++){
    $more_than_last = $array[$i] > $array[$i-1];
    $more_than_next = $array[$i] > $array[$i+1];

    $next_is_equal = $array[$i] == $array[$i+1];

    if($next_is_equal) {
      continue;
    }

    if ($i == 0) {
      if ($more_than_next) {
        $maxima[] = $array[$i];
      } else {
        $minima[] = $array[$i];
      }
    } elseif ($i == count($array)-1) {
      if ($more_than_last) {
        $maxima[] = $array[$i];
      } else {
        $minima[] = $array[$i];
      }
    } else {
      if ($more_than_last && $more_than_next) {
        $maxima[] = $array[$i];
      } elseif (!$more_than_last && !$more_than_next) {
        $minima[] = $array[$i];
      }
    }
  }

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($maxima); $i++) {
    $current_maxima = $maxima[$i];
    $next_maxima    = $maxima[$i+1];

    if ($current_maxima > $next_maxima) {
      unset($maxima[$i+1]);
    }
  }

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($minima); $i++) {
    $current_minima = $minima[$i];
    $next_minima    = $minima[$i+1];

    if ($next_minima < $current_minima) {
      unset($minima[$i]);
    }
  }

  return [
    'maxima' => array_values($maxima),
    'minima' => array_values($minima),
  ];
}

function get_turning_points($data)
{
  $mins_and_maxs = minima_and_maxima($data);

  $turning_points = [];
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($mins_and_maxs['maxima']) - 1; $i++) {
    $turning_points[] = $mins_and_maxs['maxima'][$i];
    $turning_points[] = $mins_and_maxs['minima'][$i];
  }
  $turning_points[] = $mins_and_maxs['maxima'][count($mins_and_maxs['maxima'])-1];

  return $turning_points;
}

print_r(get_turning_points($data));
```

This gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 22
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 40
)
```

Demo: https://eval.in/832708

Hope this helps :)